# Do these low profile header pins have an alternative name?

Tags: pcb, component-selection, pin-headers

I am recreating a proprietary PCB, which fits inside a plastic casing. It has these header pins with a very low profile plastic dividing piece (see photo with comparison to "standard" headers - ignore the right angle/straight difference).

Are these standard, and do they go by a specific name? I am not finding very much by searching.

I need them to be like this or the pins will not align with the casing, and I'd rather not desolder these ones if possible.

[image: comparison of normal and low profile header pins]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any specific name. However, on large distributors like digikey, you can go, find the [0.1" pin headers](https://www.digikey.de/short/dn845fdf) and constrain the results my "insulation height".

Answer (score 3):

alternative name? No.

It just a "**Insulation Height**" of around .04" to .06" based on your image.

Though not all Distros list *Insulation Height* as a searchable spec. (But LCSC and Digikey do have it)

Standard height plastic is almost a cube ~.1pitch x ~.1w x ~.1h per pin element.

The half height ones are more .05 like you have in your picture. Which is uncommon on .1" headers and much more common on 2mm pitch and 1.27mm(.05")pitch headers

Another oddity in your example board is that the bend is right at the plastic so there isn't the usual connector room (if it wasn't hanging off the board)

Normally they look like this
[image: Plastic against PCB like vertical header, then a later bend]

Or like this [image: Bend First, so the plastic lays on its side against the PCB]

What you seem to have is similar to the second style installed upside down like it was the first type which gets you

[image: reversed]

If you did that then your pin length is too short, because what was the tail-length is now the mate-length.

You could get a straight header and bend them yourself tight against the plastic, but again short *Insulation Height* in .1" is very rare to find, even more so as in-stock with min order qty 1.

The same tight-bend effect can be achieved by forcing the Pins of the first style down through the plastic, which is a by-hand alteration of the part, not something that in large quantities (and still the issue of finding send short Insulation Height part)

Since you talked about moving the old one, you don't need many of these for production, just a re-production...

---

My Recommendation is to purchase two connectors

1. Get a 5-pin .1" pitch header with a small *Insulation Height* and is Available, in-stock,  Like
   **Samtec MTLW-105-05-L-S-190** (Digikey MTLW-105-05-L-S-190-ND, Mouser 200-MTLW10505LS190  )
   Insulation Height 0.06"
   But pins are straight and very short
2. Get a 2 row right angle header with the same pin mate-length as what you have
   Looks to be .4" in you image so something like
   **TE 5-102975-4** (Mouser 571-5-102975-4, Digikey 5-102975-4-ND)
3. Pull the pins out of the Samtec header plastic, and use the second row pins from the TE part to get the tail length you need.
4. The plastic will hold the new pins well-enough, until you solder your custom header into the PCB after which it won't matter. I do pin swaps on one-offs quite a bit and this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that detail, I'll check that out

Comment: "What you seem to have is the second style installed upside down" - I can't see why you say that, other than the position of the plastic - the pin lengths seem normal from what I can see in the photo.